# Ошибка при запуске проекта avalonia.mvvm .net core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Создаю проект по шаблону avalonia.mvvm (Avalonia UI) на .net core под linux 
"sudo dotnet new avalonia.mvvm"
При попытке его запустить происходит ошибка 
"sudo dotnet run -f netcoreapp2.1"

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   view for ak_window.App    at
>   Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(Type type, Object
>   rootInstance) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Markup\Avalonia.Markup.Xaml\AvaloniaXamlLoader.cs:line 90
>   at Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(Object obj) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Markup\Avalonia.Markup.Xaml\AvaloniaXamlLoader.cs:line 45
>   at ak_window.App.Initialize() in /home/darksait88/Документы/ak_window
>   2/ak_window/App.xaml.cs:line 10    at
>   Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.Setup() in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Avalonia.Controls\AppBuilderBase.cs:line 302    at
>   Avalonia.Controls.AppBuilderBase`1.Start(AppMainDelegate main,
>   String[] args) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\Avalonia.Controls\AppBuilderBase.cs:line 153    at
>   ak_window.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   /home/darksait88/Документы/ak_window 2/ak_window/Program.cs:line 15

Comment: на их проекте на github создавали тикет? Там спрашивали?

Comment: Пока нет, но сейчас создам тогда. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Быстрее среагируют в https://gitter.im/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

Comment: А при чём тут диск `D:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас кириллица и пробелы в пути к проекту. MSBuild-таске это очень не нравится и она генерирует мусор.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, кириллица в названии пути мешала запуску приложения.